# How to write a C program fulfilling the requirements

Tags: c, algorithm

Today I came across a question. It says that:

> You need to find if a number can be expressed as sum of two perfect powers. That is, given x find if there exists non negative integers a, b, m, n such that a^m + b^n = x where 1 <= x <= 1000000 and m > 1, n > 1

Could someone please explain me how this can be done?

I know that we can write something like this:

```
for(int a = 1; true; a++){
    for(int b = 1; true; b++){
        // And so on and so forth
    }
}
```

But this is not the very efficient (or correct) way of doing so.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually with some basic math you can put some restrains on `a,b,m,n` so that the loops are really short. Because your `m,n >= 2` `a,b` should go only up to `1000` since `1000² = 1000000`

Comment: Check this [algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967769/represent-natural-number-as-sum-of-squares-using-dynamic-programming)

Comment: Well, the way I would try is to see how the power of set of all the possible valid quadruplets of `(a,b,m,n)` scales with `x`. So what is the `O( solve(x) )`. If its linear or better i'd give it a go with brute force. If it is unsatisfactory I'd ask a mathematician if there is a better (more intelligent) way to decompose numbers in such way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, that is the only way to solve these kind of problems. The one you have posted belongs to a class of problems called "one way functions": there is a trivial implementation of the problem in one way...

Given four non negative integers, `a, b, m and n, find x so a^m + b^n = x`

But the other way...

Given x, find four non negative integers `a, b, m and n, so a^m + b^n = x`

is non trivial. In fact, it could be impossible to solve it, or your best chance, have to use a force brute algorithm to solve it, which is what you have proposed.

Comment: I also like the definition of "one-way functions" or problems as "They are very hard to solve, but very easy to verify solution." It's the same of course, but worded differently. Maybe easier to grasp the meaning.